# How to make the focus able area of a clickable item non-rectangular in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have received a design like this

[image]

By default, the clickable/focus able area of **an item in listView/recyclerView is rectangular or square**.

**How to change the that?**

How do I create an adapter with focus able area of an item in RecyclerView like this picture

Need Help regarding XML layout file and adapter code,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: post your adapter layout file code

Comment: I received images design to validate and I am unable to understand how to start making it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle it by using XML  ,your item should be a FrameLayout which contain two LinearLayouts or what ever you need , the idea is the two view should have same dimension ,over each other  ,the view in background  has the background color of the next item, and facing view has different background but have left bottom  corner like the example ,

background of facing view should be in drawable folder .

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="75dp"/>
</shape>
```

your item view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
      ///////////// just a background has the same color of next element 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/next_view_color"
        android:id="@+id/background_color"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        /////////you item container 
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:background="@drawable/background_cell">
        /////////// but your item view here 
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```